# what is the appropriate data structure for this?

Tags: c++, data-structures, stack, queue

[image]

Hello I've had this question in one of the exams and I choose the Queue Is that correct ? or The most appropriate choice is the stack as my friends say ? thanks =)

Comment: A stack most closely models how the cars are physically available, but that isn't ideal for storing a list of all cars, where you probably want to search by certain criteria.

Comment: What does  "[a] car being returned [...] is parked behind the cars that are currently there. Those cannot be moved until that car is moved out" tell you about the order in which cars enter and leave?

Comment: Are you saying that a returned car can't be moved out until the cars ahead of it have been moved out? That would be First-In-First-Out (FIFO), and would require a queue. Or that a returned car must be moved before the cars ahead of it can be moved? That would be Last-In-First-Out (LIFO), and would require a stack.

Answer (score 1):

You need a stack from what I understand. If a car that is returned blocks the cars that are already in the Garage, then it's Last In First Out => Stack

Answer (score 0):

No you are not correct,answer is stack, You have some cars in garage(stack) and you return(push) another car and you must first move that car(pop) in order to move other cars which are already there.LIFO(last in first out).

Answer (score 0):

BUT "car being returned to the garage is parked ((**behind**)) the cars that are currently there." I understood from this that when we want to return a car we parked behind the current cars Is not this queue ?

Answer (score 0):

> Those cannot be moved until that car has been moved out.

According the above statement, other cars cannot be moved until the last parked car is moved out. That means LIFO data structure is needed. Therefore your friend's answer is correct. It should be stack